# InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took xxx ms. The settings might not be optimal

Tags: mysql

I use 5.7.16-10-log Percona Server on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

I recently upgraded my AWS ec2 instance to m4.4xlarge from m4.2xlarge instance type. Post the upgrade my mysql error log is periodically filled up with the following lines:

```
2017-09-15T17:10:30.678258+05:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4460ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=140, during the time.)
2017-09-15T17:14:31.048443+05:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 6047ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=107, during the time.)
2017-09-15T17:15:06.312119+05:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 8262ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=64, during the time.)
```

These are frequent when Percona Innobackupex runs as per schedule for full and incremental backups. At such times here is the disk usage as per iostat:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdf              0.00    10.00    0.00    2.00     0.00    48.00    48.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb             21.00     0.00  672.00  816.00 63328.00 104448.00   225.51    30.65   20.74   19.28   21.94   0.67 100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdf              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb              0.00     4.95  630.69  802.97 62875.25 102677.23   230.95    30.27   21.11   19.80   22.14   0.69  99.01

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdf              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb             23.00   153.00  988.00  668.00 94888.00 72104.00   201.68    26.84   16.21   14.57   18.62   0.59  98.40
```

I keep getting these messages in the mysql error log even after lowering down the lru scan depth from the default of 1024 which I found being recommended on some of the similar posts on the web.

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_lru_scan_depth=256;
```

As per someone recommending, I also tried to find out if the problem is with the LRU list or the flush list instead by using:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

In the output below, on some occasions, I was able to see flush list greater than zero in Pending writes:

```
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 50300190720
Dictionary memory allocated 18819582
Internal hash tables (constant factor + variable factor)
    Adaptive hash index 3805993024  (764908736 + 3041084288)
    Page hash           5976584 (buffer pool 0 only)
    Dictionary cache    210046766   (191227184 + 18819582)
    File system         1570552     (812272 + 758280)
    Lock system         119847848   (119530904 + 316944)
    Recovery system     0   (0 + 0)
Buffer pool size   2948760
Buffer pool size, bytes 0
Free buffers       417019
Database pages     2346130
Old database pages 866201
Modified db pages  60127
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 10, single page 0
Pages made young 5082, not young 0
0.17 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2139505, created 206625, written 1680831
1323.32 reads/s, 0.70 creates/s, 21.87 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 1314.62/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2346130, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[128], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
```

Here's a snippet of the my.cnf that I use:

```
[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir    = /usr
tmpdir   = /var/tmp
lc-messages-dir  = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
log_timestamps                 = SYSTEM
skip-name-resolve
net-write-timeout              = 600
net-read-timeout               = 600
innodb-page-cleaners           = 8
performance-schema             = OFF

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
sysdate-is-now                 = 1

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
server-id                      = 2
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1
max_binlog_size                = 1G
max_binlog_files               = 20

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 4510
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 45G
innodb-print-all-deadlocks     = ON

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
slow-query-log-file            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
lower-case-table-names         = 1
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server           = utf8mb4
collation-server               = utf8mb4_general_ci

#Slow query queries
slow-query-log                 = 1
long-query-time                = 10
slow-query-log-always-write-time = 15 #Slow query queries
log-slow-verbosity             = full
log-slow-rate-type             = query
log-slow-rate-limit            = 100 #queries logged/sec
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
```

Any advice/help/indicator to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be of great help.

Here's what limit -a looks like on my production:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 257583
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 257583
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: To me, it seems apparent that this isn't an issue with MySQL... it's simply complaining of the unexpectedly sluggish disk access it has at the moment, due to an excessive burden apparently being placed on the disk by innobackupex.  "The settings might not be optimal" in isolation... but this isn't occurring in isolation.   Are you writing the backup to the same volume where the MySQL 'datadir' is located?  Your new instance has twice the network bandwidth to EBS as the old one, which may allow the reading and writing of the backup files to stress the EBS volume beyond its capabilities.

Comment: I've a separate EBS volume for backups. Would you recommend shifting the backups to a slave server? In that case probably I'll rely on pt-table-checksum to make sure that the slave is consistent with the master and thereby the backups are good too.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_METRICS WHERE name LIKE 'buffer_%'
;` -- I'll see if I can get some clues from there.

Comment: @deb How much RAM to you have, are you using SSD or rotating hard drives?  Please post TEXT results of 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;

Answer (score 1):

Your open files are limited to 1024, raise it to 90000.
The OS cost per file is next to nothing in RAM.
Verify your change, when implemented.
Then things to do in your configuration section only 1 change, monitor 
if no negative impact, one more change the next working day, please. 
Many can be dynamically changed, see user guide.

```
thread_cache_size=100 # from 50 to minimize 
threads_created
open_files_limit=30000 # from 4510
table_definition_cache=10000 # from 4096
table_open_cache=10000 # from 4096
```

These few days worth of modification/monitoring will improve your instance.

ON ANOTHER DAY (or for an hour) for a single focus of queries not using indexes

```
slow_query_log=1  # for ON
min_examined_row_limit=1  # to eliminate useless chatter
log_queries_not_using_indexes=1 
long_query_time=5000 # for 5000 seconds which will be RARE
```

to avoid a mixed bag of slow query and queries not using indexes information

When you are finished with this single focus,

```
min_examined_row_limit=0 for useless chatter in the slow query log
log_queries_not_using_indexes=0
long_query_time=10    or less depending on your need to monitor.
```

for further analysis, 
How much RAM do you have, are you using SSD or rotating hard drives? 
Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;

Answer (score 0):

Things to do in `my.cnf/ini` [mysqld] section.

Move `innodb_page_cleaners` to be in the section # INNODB # and change to

```
innodb_page_cleaners=64 # will autolimit to be = innodb_buffer_pool_instances
```

Add a line

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8 # from default of 1 to reduce mutex contention
```

Please POST in original question results of `ulimit -a` so we can see the Ubuntu limits.

Comment: My innodb_buffer_pool_instances is already set to 8 and so is the innodb_page_cleaners. Added the output of ulimit -a to my post above.

Comment: @deb It his helpful to post complete configs/reports - your choice.  Complete MySQLTuner report would be helpful.  pastebin.com is helpful for lists/reports that exceed capacity here, show us the link.

Comment: Thanks Wilson. I've not been able to implement some of these changes which I'm beginning to do so now. I'll get back to you with the feedback.